# Shuffle an array with python, randomize array item order with python

Tags: python, arrays, random, shuffle

What's the easiest way to shuffle an array with python?

Answer (score 627, accepted):

```
import random
random.shuffle(array)
```

Comment: is there an option that doesn't mutate the original array but return a new shuffled array?

Comment: @Charlie That would be a good thing to ask in a separate question. (Maybe someone else has already asked it.)

Comment: @{Charlie Parker} Just make a copy of the original array before using random.shuffle:  
`
    copy_of array = array.copy()
    random.shuffle(copy_of_array)
`

Comment: @CharlieParker From the python docs `shuffled = sample(array, k=len(array))`

Comment: out put is  none for  a4 = np.array((blockshaped(c, 2, 3)))[3] where blockshaped return nd'array

Comment: @Tushar Despite the name, the object you get from `np.array()` is not an "array" in the sense of this question. You may want to look for another question to find out how to shuffle a _Numpy_ array specifically. (Or you can search the web to find the right page in the Numpy documentation.)

Answer (score 118):

```
import random
random.shuffle(array)
```

Answer (score 55):

Alternative way to do this using [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.shuffle.html)

```
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
X=[1,2,3]
y = ['one', 'two', 'three']
X, y = shuffle(X, y, random_state=0)
print(X)
print(y)
```

Output:

```
[2, 1, 3]
['two', 'one', 'three']
```

Advantage: You can random multiple arrays simultaneously without disrupting the mapping. And 'random_state' can control the shuffling for reproducible behavior.

Comment: Also note that the `y` is optional

Answer (score 29):

Just in case you want a new array you can use `sample`:

```
import random
new_array = random.sample( array, len(array) )
```

Answer (score 21):

The other answers are the easiest, however it's a bit annoying that the `random.shuffle` method doesn't actually return anything - it just sorts the given list.  If you want to chain calls or just be able to declare a shuffled array in one line you can do:

```
import random
def my_shuffle(array):
    random.shuffle(array)
    return array
```

Then you can do lines like:

```
for suit in my_shuffle(['hearts', 'spades', 'clubs', 'diamonds']):
```

Comment: It doesn't return anything *specifically* because it is trying to remind you that it works by altering the input in place.  (This can save memory.)  Your function alters its input in place also.

Comment: I guess it's a style thing. Personally I prefer the fact that I can write a single line to achieve what would take a couple otherwise. It seems odd to me that a language which aims to allow programs to be as short as possible doesn't tend to return the passed object in these cases.  Since it alters the input in place, you can replace a call to random.shuffle for a call to this version without issue.

Comment: Python doesn't actually aim to be as brief as possible.  Python aims to balance readability with expressivity.  It so happens to be fairly brief, mainly because it is a very high-level language.  Python's own built-ins *typically* (not always) strive to *either* be "functionlike" (return a value, but don't have side effects) *or* be "procedurelike" (operate via side effects, and don't return anything).  This goes hand-in-hand with Python's quite strict distinction between statements and expressions.

Comment: Nice. I suggest renaming it to my_shuffle to see the difference in the code immediately.

Comment: Maybe, but this could be premature optimization (it could be helpful, but the need to shuffle doesn't explicitly require the need to return the array). Also, shuffle(array) followed by some use of shuffle would only be 2 lines as opposed to 3 + n (times usage), although I guess it would be a saving if you use it many times. Here is a great video that discusses this type of thing (e.g. phantom requirements and premature optimisation) - http://pyvideo.org/video/880/stop-writing-classes

Answer (score 15):

When dealing with regular Python lists, `random.shuffle()` will do the job just as the previous answers show.

But when it come to `ndarray`(`numpy.array`), `random.shuffle` seems to break the original `ndarray`. Here is an example:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import numpy.random

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
a.shape = (3,2)
print a
random.shuffle(a) # a will definitely be destroyed
print a
```

Just use: `np.random.shuffle(a)`

Like `random.shuffle`, `np.random.shuffle` shuffles the array in-place.

Comment: what does destroyed mean, exactly?  (i mean, in this context -- i'm not an ELL.)

Comment: Well if I try A = np.array(range(9)).reshape([3,3])

Answer (score 7):

You can sort your array with random key

```
sorted(array, key = lambda x: random.random())
```

key only be read once so comparing item during sort still efficient.

but look like `random.shuffle(array)` will be faster since it written in C

this is O(Nlog(N)) btw

Comment: This is O(n log n), not O(log n), and inherently slower than an O(n) shuffle, C aspect aside.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the previous replies, I would like to introduce another function.

`numpy.random.shuffle` as well as `random.shuffle` perform in-place shuffling. However, if you want to return a shuffled array `numpy.random.permutation` is the function to use.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know I used `random.shuffle()` but it return 'None' to me, so I wrote this, might helpful to someone

```
def shuffle(arr):
    for n in range(len(arr) - 1):
        rnd = random.randint(0, (len(arr) - 1))
        val1 = arr[rnd]
        val2 = arr[rnd - 1]

        arr[rnd - 1] = val1
        arr[rnd] = val2

    return arr
```

Comment: yes it returns None, but array is modifed, if you really want to return something then do this

import random
def shuffle(arr):
    random.shuffle(arr)
    return arr

Comment: This swaps n−1 random pairs of adjacent items, which isn’t a correct (uniform) shuffle.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that `random.shuffle()` should not be used on multi-dimensional arrays as it causes repetitions.

Imagine you want to shuffle an array along its first dimension, we can create the following test example,

```
import numpy as np
x = np.zeros((10, 2, 3))

for i in range(10):
   x[i, ...] = i*np.ones((2,3))
```

so that along the first axis, the i-th element corresponds to a 2x3 matrix where all the elements are equal to i.

If we use the correct shuffle function for multi-dimensional arrays, i.e. `np.random.shuffle(x)`, the array will be shuffled along the first axis as desired. However, using `random.shuffle(x)` will cause repetitions. You can check this by running `len(np.unique(x))` after shuffling which gives you 10 (as expected) with `np.random.shuffle()` but only around 5 when using `random.shuffle()`.

Answer (score -1):

```
# arr = numpy array to shuffle

def shuffle(arr):
    a = numpy.arange(len(arr))
    b = numpy.empty(1)
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        sel = numpy.random.random_integers(0, high=len(a)-1, size=1)
        b = numpy.append(b, a[sel])
        a = numpy.delete(a, sel)
    b = b[1:].astype(int)
    return arr[b]
```