# elegant way to disorder a list

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shuffle an array with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473973/shuffle-an-array-with-python)

let's say I have a list `myList=[1,2,3,4,5]`,and I want to disorder it randomly:

```
disorder(myList) # myList is something like [5,3,2,1,4] or [3,5,1,2,4] now
```

the way I am using is

```
from random import randint
upperBound = len(myList)-1
for i in range(10):
    myList.insert(randint(0, upperBound), myList.pop(randint(0, upperBound)))
```

this works, but I think it's obviously inelegant. I am wondering whether there is an elegant and efficient way to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `random.shuffle()` to shuffle the list in-place:

```
>>> import random
>>> l = range(10)
>>> l
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> random.shuffle(l)
>>> l
    [0, 2, 8, 7, 9, 1, 3, 4, 6, 5]
```

Answer (score 9):

If you already imported random:

```
random.shuffle(myList)
```

It shuffles the `myList` inplace. It means you have just to run this command, do not use the returning value of this function, which is always `None`.