# How to shuffle an array so that all elements change their place?

Tags: python-2.7

I need to shuffle an array so that all array elements should change their location. Given an array [0,1,2,3] it would be ok to get [1,0,3,2] or [3,2,0,1] but not [3,1,2,0].

Is there any function in python to do this or I have to do this myself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shuffle an array with python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473973/shuffle-an-array-with-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shortest solution I can think of would be to use `random.shuffle(v)` to shuffle and check the result until all elements are in a different location:

```
while not allDifferent(v):
    random.shuffle(v)
```

The risk of this is of course that you may potentially have to try many times, but that is not a very big problem. After running some tests on this, the average number of attempts before all elements are in a different position is about 3 for list length 3. 2.7 for list length 5, and then it seems to stay around 2.7 for longer lists (tried up to length 1000).

It's a bit iffy to rely on the probability like that, but for most applications you should be fine.

Edit: Now if you would prefer something faster, you would probably have to do it yourself. Something like this:

```
for i in range(0, len(a)-1):
    pick = random.randint(i+1, len(a)-1)
    a[i], a[pick] = a[pick], a[i]
```

That one will shuffle the array so that no number ends up in the same place as before (because of the `i+1`).