# program that jumble letters in word

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering how to make a program where the user
types a word and then the program jumbles the letters in the word in a random way.

I've thought a lot about this and failed. I made the program below but its not good at all because I want to jumble the letters and this program just randomly
assigns each index one of the letters. This means the same letter can repeat 
itself several times, like for example:   **Input:** `apple`. **Output:** `ppppp`

```
import random

print('Type a word!')
i = 0
wordJ = ''

word = input()
word = str(word)
while i < len(word):
    wordJ = wordJ + word[random.randrange(len(word))]
    i = i + 1

print(wordJ)
```

Comment: You already have the random module, just use `random.shuffle`.

Comment: Is this homework? This feels like homework... Specially with the *"I was wondering how..."* falls in line with the *"I was teaching myself..."* and learning how to shuffle..

see http://stackoverflow.com/a/473983/1111028

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the string in `word` you could shuffle it like this

```
from random import shuffle
word = list(word)
shuffle(word)
word = "".join(word)
print(word)
```

Comment: import random
    print('Type a word!')

    word = input()
    word = list(word)
    random.shuffle(list(word))
    wordJ = ''.join(word)
    print(wordJ)

Comment: why does it not work to use enter to change row

Comment: I was wondering why this solution does not shuffle the word but it returns the word unchanged

Comment: It works check here
https://repl.it/Dipx/0

Comment: okey, thank you it works :) when i tried to type the program above its all on the same row, why is that? i didnt type it all on the same row

Comment: Dont know, may be comments are not capable to have multiline code,
In case my answer works for then you can upvote and accept as answer.

Comment: okay i think i have done that now :)

Answer (score -1):

```
import random

word = input()
word = list(word)
random.shuffle(word)

wordJ = ''.join(word)
print(wordJ)
```

Comment: Did you even try this?

Comment: Nope, I just wanted quick rep. There, I fixed it for you.