# Random order generator using filtering and recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a random order generator. I have a list of ten names and want to write a program that returns the same list in a random order.

Here is my code which I'm told has invalid syntax in line 11

[image: current code] .

I am trying to complete the problem using filtering and recursion to further my understanding of these tools.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post your code as text in the body. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shuffle an array with python, randomize array item order with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473973/shuffle-an-array-with-python-randomize-array-item-order-with-python)

Comment: Post code into the question and don't forget to format it properly.

Comment: ...are you using the digit `0` for a capital `O`?

Comment: The error is because your `if: else:` statement makes no sense. You use this statement for doing one thing or another. However you have a random block of code (pick, new_list) between the if block (which is 1 line, a return statement) and the else block.

Comment: @Denziloe I am not using the digit 0 for a capital O. I am using a capital O.

Comment: @WillCole Okay, good. Your interpreter has a weird font. Which is just one more reason that you should always post text here, as others have requested, not pictures.

Answer (score 2):

[random.shuffle()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) is what you are looking for.

Comment: When I use random.shuffle(), the terminal prints 'None'. Am I wasting my time trying to solve it with filtering and recursion?

Comment: @Will Call shuffle on its own, then print out the list. Don't print out the shuffle method, which returns nothing

Comment: random.shuffle() works in place, it does not return anything

Comment: @WillCole Considering you're not creating this code for actual use, but rather to educate yourself, no you are not wasting your time. I would recommend you try to fix your approach first, it shows that you have several lessons to learn.