# How can I randomly change the index of an array?

Tags: python

I have an array which shape is (100,784), float type.

And I want to change the index of columns randomly.

Many have suggested the random function, but I want to change the index of the row without changing the index of the column at all. Please help. thank you.

Comment: Use the random library, `random.shuffle(list)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shuffle an array with python, randomize array item order with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473973/shuffle-an-array-with-python-randomize-array-item-order-with-python)

Comment: Are you trying to just shuffle the array within the 2d arrays

Comment: yes. and only for row index.